# How to allocate the good RAM amount for java process?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, memory-management

I have the feeling that it is nearly impossible to accurately control how much RAM memory will be used by a java process. Best example is Eclipse, you can use `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` to say that the memory to be used is at least 256m (because you are sure to get an OOM error below this value), and that the heap should not be bigger than 512m (but that accounts only for the heap, and the process memory can reach values like 800m or even more)

I also have the feeling that 90% of the time, after one or two hours your heap will allways reach the `-Xmx` value whatever be it. Once again, best example is Eclipse: run it with `-Xmx512m`, its process will use around 800MB of RAM. Run it again with `-Xmx1024m`, and two hours later the exact same process in the exact same conditions will use around 1200MB or RAM.

My conclusion is that by nature, java processes are greedy and that they will always use as much memory as they are allowed to whatever how high is their upper limit (which I believe can't be bigger than 2 or 3GB by default anyway on java hotspot).

When I read related questions such as [How to calculate (and specify) the total memory space allowed for java process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513903/how-to-calculate-and-specify-the-total-memory-space-allowed-for-java-process), I can see that at least until the date of the question, everybody has proceed like I proceed, which is raising the `-Xmx` value by a small amount every time there is a memory problem. But that question is from 2010. I can't believe that in 2015 a java process can't be reasonable and try to free as much memory as possible instead of eating whatever it is allowed to and even more??

Comment: Why shouldn't Java use up as much space as you allow? Since garbage collection can be resource intensive depending on the method used, typically it is delayed for as long as is reasonable.  You may find [JVM performance optimization, Part 3: Garbage collection](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078645/java-se/jvm-performance-optimization-part-3-garbage-collection.html) interesting as well as [Memory Management in the Java HotSpot VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf).

Comment: I want to save as much RAM as possible whatever the CPU cost and java don't allows that

Comment: Then I suggest a language appropriate to worrying about memory and performance such as C++ or C.

Comment: Should I made a ticket to Elasticsearch and Eclipse developpers to tell them to recode to C++? :(

Answer (score 0):

This memory that is out of the range of your XMX is probably the **Permanent memory space (PermGen)**, which is out of the HEAP memory, controlled by the **XMS/XMX**.

I normally try to set it like this:

```
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

Another thing that I do is set both Xmx and Xmx to its maximum value. So it already allocate the entire HEAP space the eclipse will use (plus the permgen)

Below a great blog post that gives some tips about mem config with eclipse:

http://devwithpassion.com/handrus/boost-eclipse-performance-also-works-for-zendstudio/

Comment: That link you gave is full of mistakes. Especially the "_D Advanced Optmizations_" paragraph. For example the `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` flag has nothing to do with permSizes.