# How to gracefully tell Java about total memory limits?

Tags: java, memory

I have troubles with Java memory consumption.

I'd like to say to Java something like this: "you have 8GB of memory, please use it, and only it. Only if you really can't put all your resources in this memory pool, then fail with OOM".

I know, there are default parameters like -Xmx - they limit only the heap. There are also plenty of other parameters, I know. The problems with these parameters are:

- They aren't relevant. I don't want to limit the heap size to 6GB (and trust that native memory won't take more than 2GB). I do want to limit all the memory (heap, native, whatever). And do that effectively, not just saying "-Xmx1GB" - to be safe.
- There is too many different parameters related to memory, and I don't know how to configure all of them to achieve the goal.

So, I don't want to go there and care about heap, perm and whatever types of memory. My high-level expectation is: since there is only 8GB, and some static memory is needed - take the static memory from the 8GB, and carefully split the remaining memory between other dynamic memory entities.

Also, ulimit and similar things don't work. I don't want to kill the java process once it consumes more memory than expected. I want Java does its best to not reach the limit firstly, and only if it really, really can't - kill the process.

And I'm OK to define even 100 java parameters, why not. :) But then I need assistance with the full list of needed parameters (for, say, Java 8).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513903/how-to-calculate-and-specify-the-total-memory-space-allowed-for-java-process ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no `java` command line parameter or set of parameters that will do that.

Your best bet (IMO) is to set the max heap size and the max metaspace size and *hope* that other things are going to be pretty static / predictable for your application.  (It won't cover the size of the JVM binary and it probably won't cover native libraries, memory mapped files, stacks and so on.)

In a comment you said:

> So I'm forced to have a significant amount of memory unused to be safe.

I think you are worrying about the wrong thing here.  Assuming that you are not constrained by address space or swap space limitations, memory that is *never* used doesn't matter.

If a page of your address space is not used, the OS will (in the long term) swap it out, and give the physical RAM page to something else.

Pages in the heap won't be in that situation in a typical Java application.  (Address space pages will cycle between in-use and free as the GC moves objects within and between "spaces".)

However, the flip-side is that a GC **needs** the total heap size to be significantly larger than the sum of the live objects.  If too much of the heap is occupied with reachable objects, the interval between garbage collection runs decreases, and your GC ergonomics suffer.  In the worst case, a JVM can grind to a halt as the time spent in the GC tends to 100%.  Ugly.  The GC overhead limit mechanism prevents this, but that just means that your JVM gets an OOME sooner.

So, in the normal heap case, a better way to think about it is that you need to keep a portion of memory "unused" so that the GC can operate efficiently.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for such a confirmation. I'll try to hope and pray carefully. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-XX:MetaspaceSize`?
Is this what you need?

Please, read this article: http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/one-important-change-in-memory-management-in-java-8/

Keep in mind that this is only valid to Java 8.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did. As I already said, -XX:MetaspaceSize with -Xmx together just limit the dynamic memory allocation (or I at least hope so, because I'm not 100% sure). But the thing is that I can't predict properly the static part. So I'm forced to have a significant amount of memory unused to be safe. 

Moreover, these two limitations are very stupid because, to be honest, I don't care if some memory from heap will be used for metadata or vice versa.